# When can ADAL tokens be shared? (iOS)

Tags: ios, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

In my application, I am getting an access token via ADAL's acquireTokenSilent() for one resource, which succeeds, and then I try to get an access token for another resource and it says it was not found, and hence I have to call the API to explicitly prompt for credentials. This is a problem since then the user has to login twice with the same credentials in order to access two different resources.

I am using the same authority for each resource. Here is the message that shows there is no hit in the cache for the second resource.

May  4 13:22:37 iPad MyApp[290] : ADAL 2.4.1 iOS 10.2.1 [2017-05-04 20:22:37 - XXXX] INFO: No items were found for query: (resource https://MYRESOURCE + client  + authority https://login.windows.net/common)

So my question is, under what circumstances will tokens be shared across resources, and is there any special allowances (ways to use the APIs) which allow this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building two native clients (public clients) and you want to enable single sign on across the two, one option is to share the App ID between the apps versus passing the actual token from one service to another service.

For example lets say your company name is Contoso. You have a Calendar Mobile App, and a Document Editor App.

You can create a single Native Client Application with:

- A common application name, like "Contoso Apps"
- Redirect URIs for both apps
- Permissions required for the sum of the two applications

Then when a user signs into either application, they will see a login screen with the generic name "Contoso Apps", and prompted to consent to permissions for both apps at the same time. Now this might be a little bit of a bad experience, since the permissions of the two will probably be more than the individual permissions required, but that could be fixed in the future with [Incremental Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#incremental-and-dynamic-consent).

Then assuming you are using our authentication libraries which automatically caches the access tokens, when the user opens the second application, they will not be prompted to consent because you already have a token cached for that Application ID.

This obviously is not the best solution, but one that has been used in the past for large enterprise applications.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My problem is slightly different as I am only using a single app but trying to access two different resources. I am not sure if you answer applies to this scenario or not, can you please clarify?

Comment: I see, I slightly misinterpreted your question. Read this article about [Multi-Resource Refresh Tokens](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/14/adal-windows-azure-ad-and-multi-resource-refresh-tokens/).